# Is downloading file through PHP or through direct link faster?

Tags: php, performance, pdf

I need to get user download some file (for example, PDF). What will be longer:

- send this file by PHP (with specific headers),
- or put it in http public folder, and get user the public link to download it (without PHP help)?

In 1st case the original file could be in private zone. 
But I'm thinking it will take some time to send this file by PHP.

So how I can measure PHP spent time to sending file and how much memory it can consumed?

P.S. in the 1st case, when PHP sends headers and browser (if pdf plugin is installed) will try to opening it inside browser, is PHP still working, or it push out whole file after headers sent immediately? Or if plugin not installed and browser will show "save as" dialog PHP still working ?

Comment: The time spent by PHP for either of those is negligible. What will make a difference is your and the client's network connectivity. In other words: you do not have to measure the time. Just implement one solution.

Comment: in case when PHP will send file, and user will look on "save as" dialog and decide what to do, PHP will wait user answer? memory will be used ? till user decide click save or cancel, right ?

Answer (score 2):

There will be very little in it if you are worried about download speeds.

I guess it comes down to how big your files are, how many downloads you expect to have, and if your documents should be publicly accessible, the download speed of the client.

Comment: the main concern here is memory usage.
I'm thinking that single Apache will eat lesser memory then Apache + PHP. It seems that PHP will keep spent memory even if user will think what to do in "save as" dialog. What do you think ?

Comment: yes, php might use more memory. Serving the file as a static file I personally think will be the most benificial, and easiest to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue with PHP is the memory it consumes - each link will create a new process, which would be maybe 8M - 20M depending on what your script does, whether you use a framework etc.

Out of interest, I wrote a symfony application to offer downloads, and to do things like concurrency limiting, bandwidth limiting etc. It's [here](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/07/bandwidth-project-offering-direct-downloads-without-breaking-limits/) if you're interested in taking a look at the code. (I've not licensed it per se, but I'm happy to make it GPL3 if you like).

Comment: this is my concern here. What if 1K people will try to open each own file ? In case if files will be sent by Apache alone, it seems that memory spend will be lesser.

Comment: Correct. In general, you should only use a scripted process if you want to do something fancy like concurrency limiting (and even that can be done by Apache, if you use the right optional modules). If you just want to offer password/session-based security, then you can create unguessable directory structures (perhaps including a hash) and create a symlink from inside that structure to the real file outside of the web tree. A cron-job can be used to delete expired folders.

Comment: Side note: if your PHP process takes 16M, then 1000 concurrent users would take up approximately 16G of RAM - which is fine if you have your own server. But, of course, you could limit your system to deny requests to excess users during busy periods. Finally, it is worth doing some research to see what levels of requests you could reasonably get: most projections of site popularity are over-estimated, imo.